# OnCollision Enter not displaying a debug log

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerCollision : MonoBehaviour
{
    void onCollisionEnter (){
        Debug.Log("We hit something.");    
    }
}
```

I have rigidbody on every object and I attacked the script to my object, but still not working. I am following a Brackeys tutorial and it is a little old so I don't know if something has changed about the syntax.

Comment: did you attach  the component to your gameobject?

Comment: Capital O on OnCollisionEnter.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

```
void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision) {

}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).